# Kotlin JPA plugin with Spring Boot 2 error

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

Having problems starting application with Spring Boot 2 and applied kotlin-jpa plugin. But works fine with Spring Boot 1.5.9.

java version - 1.8
kotlin version - 1.2.41
spring boot version - 2.0.1.RELEASE

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils$KotlinDelegate.findPrimaryConstructor(BeanUtils.java:727) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.findPrimaryConstructor(BeanUtils.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1198) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.reflect.full.KClasses
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you should add **kotlin-reflect** dependency from [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.41)