# spring:: lateinit property userRepo has not been initialized

Tags: spring, kotlin

### DataTable.kt

```kotlin
class DataTable(private val param: MultiValueMap<String, String>, private val searchField: Array<String>) {
    @Autowired
    private val userService: UserService = UserService()

    private fun getAllCnt(): Int {
        return userService.countAll()
    }
```

### UserRepo.kt

```kotlin
@Repository
interface UserRepo: JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query(value="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users", nativeQuery=true)
    fun countAll(): Int
}
```

### UserService.kt

```kotlin
@Service
class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userRepo: UserRepo

    fun countAll(): Int {
        return userRepo.countAll()
    }
}
```

---

### error

> lateinit property userRepo has not been initialized

maybe I think not define userRepo.
but I don't know how to define userRepo.

Comment: Check this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50134525/kotlin-jpa-plugin-with-spring-boot-2-error

Comment: @SimrandeepSingh thank you for your comment but i don't know why recommend this question.

Comment: The answer says to add kotlin-reflect dependency for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/reflect/full/KClasses. Hence thought this might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Using `lateinit`
doesn't seem necessary.

Try fixing it like this

Before change

```kotlin
@Service
class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userRepo: UserRepo

    fun countAll(): Int {
        return userRepo.countAll()
    }
}
```

After

```kotlin
@Service
class UserService(
    private val userRepo: UserRepo
) {

    fun countAll(): Int {
        return userRepo.countAll()
    }
}
```